# Selecting multiple fields in subquery

Tags: abap, opensql

This ABAP code works:

```
  select *
   into table <sub_result>
  from ADRC
  WHERE ADDRNUMBER
  in ( select ADRNRA from AUFK where (cond_string) ).
```

But this does not:

```
  select *
   into table <sub_result>
  from ADRC
  WHERE (ADDRNUMBER, MANDT)
  in ( select ADRNRA, MANDT from AUFK where (cond_string) ).
```

AFAIK the tuple syntax `(ADDRNUMBER, MANDT)` is valid for SQL. Is this not valid in Open SQL of ABAP?

If the tuple syntax is not allowed, what could I do?

**P.S.** In Open SQL checking for MANDT is not needed, so this is only sample query.

Comment: Do EXISTS instead on IN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete Pelin's answer, here are two possible syntaxes, depending on the ABAP version :

```
DATA sflights TYPE TABLE OF sflight.

" Strict mode of OpenSQL (>= 7.40 SP 5 ; more syntaxes than old OpenSQL syntax)

SELECT * FROM sflight AS f INTO TABLE @sflights  " <== @ activates the strict mode
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sbook AS b    " <== 1 is possible in strict mode
        WHERE b~carrid = f~carrid
          AND b~connid = f~connid
          AND b~fldate = f~fldate ).

" "Loose" mode of OpenSQL (strict mode not used)

SELECT * FROM sflight AS f INTO TABLE sflights " <== no @ i.e. strict mode deactivated
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sbook AS b  " <== 1 is not possible
        WHERE b~carrid = f~carrid
          AND b~connid = f~connid
          AND b~fldate = f~fldate ).
```

Comment: Dear Sandra Rossi. Thank you very much for your help. Is there a way to send you a bunch of flowers? Your help here on StackOverlow priceless.

Comment: Thanks, you're welcome. I prefer well-formed StackOverflow questions - keep on!

Answer (score 5):

You can not use in for multiple columns. Try like this:

```
SELECT *
  INTO table <sub_result>
  FROM ADRC d
  WHERE exists ( select 1 from AUFK a where a~ADDRNUMBER = d~ADDRNUMBER and a~MANDT = d~MANDT)
```

Comment: in ABAP, it makes a syntax error if you use `.` after the table alias. Instead you must use `~`.

Comment: Note sure if I'm right: if you use `select 1`, then it works only in the **strict mode** of OpenSQL, so you should use `@` in front of variables (`@<sub_result>`). In non-strict mode, you may use `WHERE exists ( select *`

Comment: only `~` (not `~.`)

Comment: @SandraRossi I learned that checking for MANDT/CLIENT is not needed in Open SQL. I updated the question. Is the text I added to the question (after "Update" ...) correct?

Comment: @guettli Right ! (sorry to not have seen that :))

Comment: I confirm my first feeling about the strict mode. I prefer to add a new answer so that to make it more clear.

Comment: And just for clarity: IN with tuples is perfectly valid SQL. However, OpenSQL is only a subset of SQL and does not support multi-valued tuples in the IN clause.